# Custom Menus Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 custom menus that trigger when we open the spreadsheet

Problem is the order keeps changing each time I open the Spreadsheet

I would like it to appear in the exact same order each time - like File, edit, view etc

```
function MailMergeMENU() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu("MAIL MERGE")
.addItem("1.Star Track Import(MailMerge)","PrepareMailMerge")
.addSeparator()
.addItem("2.Send D2D SENT/Save File","D2DSENT")
.addToUi();

}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, I think that in your question, one custom menu can be created with `MailMergeMENU()`. About `I have 3 custom menus that trigger when we open the spreadsheet. Problem is the order keeps changing each time I open the Spreadsheet`, can you provide the script for replicating your issue? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: The OP probably has 3 projects with three different menus.  I see the same thing in a couple spreadsheets where I have multiple projects attached.

Comment: Hi Tanaike the above code is copied 2 other times that run other functions. So when we open the spreadsheet the custom menus appear -  Clear Form, D2D MACRO, MAILMERGE. You then close the spreadsheet and reopen and they appear D2DMACRO MAILMERGE CLEARFORM. if you close again and reopen they appear MAILMERGE D2DMACRO CLEARFORM. they keep changing and i would like them to stay in the same position all the time. hope that makes sense

Comment: Cooper - did you have any luck stopping the menus from changing position ?

Comment: No. It doesn't bother me.

Comment: How are you loading the rest of the menus? Are they in different projects then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try in this way:

```
function onOpen(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menuList= [
    {name: "1.Star Track Import(MailMerge)", functionName: "PrepareMailMerge"}, 
    {name: "2.Send D2D SENT/Save File", functionName: "D2DSENT"}
];
var menuList2= [
    {name: "My menu name", functionName: "myFunction1"}, 
    {name: "2My menu name2", functionName: "myFunction2"}
];

ss.addMenu("MAIL MERGE", menuList);
ss.addMenu("CLEAR FORM", menuList);
}
```

I have used this and my menu stays the same all the time.

Comment: Hi krismans - the issue is not within each menu - the issue is the 3 custom menus I have - MAILMERGE, D2DMACRO, CLEARFORM. They keep changing position everytime i reopen the spreadsheet. So they will appear MAILMERGE, D2DMACRO, CLEARFORM then close and reopen and , D2DMACRO, CLEARFORM,MAILMERGE and if you close and reopen they appear like CLEARFORM,MAILMERGE, D2DMACRO. I would like them to stay MAILMERGE, D2DMACRO, CLEARFORM everytime I open Spreadsheet (like File, Edit, view etc)

Comment: Did you tried this way as I showed? In this way, you can add more than one menu and it should stay in the same order all the time. Just create more menuLists and add more ss.addMenu() functions and it should stay in one order. I have 3 additional menus in my spreadsheet and I don`t see them changing an order. I have edited my answer above with two menus. Try it and let me know.

Comment: That`s great. Good luck.